# Accent Sensitive Sort

Tags: sql-server, collation, unicode

Why do these two `SELECT` statements result in a different sort order?

```
USE tempdb;
CREATE TABLE dbo.OddSort 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , col1 NVARCHAR(2)
    , col2 NVARCHAR(2)
);
GO
INSERT dbo.OddSort (col1, col2) 
VALUES (N'e', N'eA')
    , (N'é', N'éB')
    , (N'ë', N'ëC')
    , (N'è', N'èD')
    , (N'ê', N'êE')
    , (N'ē', N'ēF');
GO

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.OddSort 
ORDER BY col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS;
```

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╗
║ id ║ col1 ║ col2 ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ e    ║ eA   ║
║  2 ║ é    ║ éB   ║
║  4 ║ è    ║ èD   ║  -- should be id 3?
║  5 ║ ê    ║ êE   ║
║  3 ║ ë    ║ ëC   ║
║  6 ║ ē    ║ ēF   ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╝
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.OddSort 
ORDER BY col2 COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS;
```

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╗
║ id ║ col1 ║ col2 ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ e    ║ eA   ║
║  2 ║ é    ║ éB   ║
║  3 ║ ë    ║ ëC   ║
║  4 ║ è    ║ èD   ║
║  5 ║ ê    ║ êE   ║
║  6 ║ ē    ║ ēF   ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question is not so related to databases but more on Unicode handling and rules.

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/windows-collation-name-transact-sql *Latin1_General_100_CS_AS* means: "Collation uses the Latin1 General dictionary sorting rules and maps to code page 1252" with the added CS = Case Sensitive and AS = Accent Sensitive.

The mapping between Windows code page 1252 and Unicode (http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT) show the same values for all characters we are dealing with (except e with macron that does not exist in Microsoft mapping, so no idea what it does with this case), so we can concentrate on Unicode tools and terminology for now.

First, let us know precisely what we are dealing with, for all your strings:

```
0065  LATIN SMALL LETTER E
0041  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
00E9  LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
0042  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
00EB  LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS
0043  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
00E8  LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE
0044  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
00EA  LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX
0045  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
‎0113  LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH MACRON
0046  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
```

The Unicode Collation Algorithm is described here: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/

Have a look at section 1.3 "Contextual Sensitivity" that explains that the sorting can not depend on just one character after the other as some rules are context sensitive.

Note also these points in 1.8:

> Collation is not a property of strings.
>   Collation order is not preserved under concatenation or substring operations, in general.
>
> By default, the algorithm makes use of three fully-customizable levels. For the Latin script, these levels correspond roughly to:

```
alphabetic ordering
diacritic ordering
case ordering.
```

But the algorithm by itself is a little dense. The gist of it is: *Briefly stated, the Unicode Collation Algorithm takes an input Unicode string and a Collation Element Table, containing mapping data for characters. It produces a sort key, which is an array of unsigned 16-bit integers. Two or more sort keys so produced can then be binary-compared to give the correct comparison between the strings for which they were generated.*

You can view the specific Latin sorting rules here: http://developer.mimer.com/collations/charts/latin.htm
or more directly and specifically for MS SQL:
http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0409.1252.Latin1_General_CS_AS.html

For the `e` character it shows:

> e E é É è È ê Ê ë Ë

This explains your results when ordering on `col1` except that ē does not exists in code page 1252, so I have absolutely no ideas what it does with it.

Or if we do the Unicode algorithm by hand, using the keys value of DUCET at http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/latest/allkeys.txt :

step 1: Normalization form D, so each case becomes:

```
e => U+0065
é => U+0065 U+0301
ë => U+0065 U+0308
è => U+0065 U+0300
ê => U+0065 U+0302
ē => U+0065 U+0304
```

step 2, Produce collation arrays (lookup in file `allkeys.txt`)

```
e => [.1D10.0020.0002]
é => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0024.0002]
ë => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.002B.0002]
è => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0025.0002]
ê => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0027.0002]
ē => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0032.0002]
```

step 3, Form sort keys (for each level, take each value inside each collation array, then put 0000 as delimitator and start again for next level)

```
e => 1D10 0000 0020 0000 0002
é => 1D10 0000 0020 0024 0000 0002 0002
ë => 1D10 0000 0020 002B 0000 0002 0002
è => 1D10 0000 0020 0025 0000 0002 0002
ê => 1D10 0000 0020 0027 0000 0002 0002
ē => 1D10 0000 0020 0032 0000 0002 0002
```

step 4, Compare sort keys (simple binary comparison of each value one by one):
The fourth value is enough to sort them all, so the final order becomes:

```
e
é
è
ê
ë
ē
```

In the same way for ordering on `col2`:

step 1 : NFD

```
eA => U+0065 U+0041
éB => U+0065 U+0301 U+0042
ëC => U+0065 U+0308 U+0043
èD => U+0065 U+0300 U+0044
êE => U+0065 U+0302 U+0045
ēF => U+0065 U+0304 U+0046
```

step 2 : Collation arrays

```
eA => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.1CAD.0020.0008]
éB => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0024.0002] [.1CC6.0020.0008]
ëC => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.002B.0002] [.1CE0.0020.0008]
èD => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0025.0002] [.1CF5.0020.0008]
êE => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0027.0002] [.1D10.0020.0008]
ēF => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0032.0002] [.1D4B.0020.0008]
```

step 3 : Form sort keys

```
eA => 1D10 1CAD 0000 0020 0020 0000 0002 0008
éB => 1D10 1CC6 0000 0020 0024 0020 0000 0002 0002 0008
ëC => 1D10 1CE0 0000 0020 002B 0020 0000 0002 0002 0008
èD => 1D10 1CF5 0000 0020 0025 0020 0000 0002 0002 0008
êE => 1D10 1D10 0000 0020 0027 0020 0000 0002 0002 0008
ēF => 1D10 1D4B 0000 0020 0032 0020 0000 0002 0002 0008
```

step 4 : Compare sort keys:
The second value is enough to sort them all, and it is in fact already in increasing order, so the final order is indeed:

```
eA
éB
ëC
èD
êE
ēF
```

**Update**: adding Solomon Rutzky third case, which is trickier because of the space that enables new rules (I chose the "non-ignorable case"):

step 1, NFD:

```
è 1 => U+0065 U+0300 U+0020 U+0031
ê 5 => U+0065 U+0302 U+0020 U+0035
e 2 => U+0065 U+0020 U+0032
é 4 => U+0065 U+0301 U+0020 U+0034
ē 3 => U+0065 U+0304 U+0020 U+0033
ë 6 => U+0065 U+0308 U+0020 U+0036
```

step 2, Produce collation arrays:

```
è 1 => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0025.0002] [*0209.0020.0002] [.1CA4.0020.0002]
ê 5 => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0027.0002] [*0209.0020.0002] [.1CA8.0020.0002]
e 2 => [.1D10.0020.0002] [*0209.0020.0002] [.1CA5.0020.0002]
é 4 => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0024.0002] [*0209.0020.0002] [.1CA7.0020.0002]
ē 3 => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.0032.0002] [*0209.0020.0002] [.1CA6.0020.0002]
ë 6 => [.1D10.0020.0002] [.0000.002B.0002] [*0209.0020.0002] [.1CA9.0020.0002]
```

step 3, Form sort keys:

```
è 1 => 1D10 0209 1CA4 0000 0020 0025 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0002
ê 5 => 1D10 0209 1CA8 0000 0020 0027 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0002
e 2 => 1D10 0209 1CA5 0000 0020 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002
é 4 => 1D10 0209 1CA7 0000 0020 0024 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0002
ē 3 => 1D10 0209 1CA6 0000 0020 0032 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0002
ë 6 => 1D10 0209 1CA9 0000 0020 002B 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0002
```

step 4, Compare sort keys:

Basically the third value determines the order, and it is in fact only based on the last digit, so the order should be:

```
è 1
e 2
ē 3
é 4
ê 5
ë 6
```

**Second update** based on Solomon Rutzky's comment about Unicode versions.

I used the `allkeys.txt` data about latest Unicode version at this time, that is version 10.0

If we need to take instead into account **Unicode 5.1**, this would be:
http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/5.1.0/allkeys.txt

I just checked, for all the characters above, the collation arrays are the
following instead:

```
e => [.119D.0020.0002.0065]
é => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.0032.0002.0301]
ë => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.0047.0002.0308]
è => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.0035.0002.0300]
ê => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.003C.0002.0302]
ē => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.005B.0002.0304]
```

and:

```
eA => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.1141.0020.0008.0041]
éB => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.0032.0002.0301] [.1157.0020.0008.0042]
ëC => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.0047.0002.0308] [.116F.0020.0008.0043]
èD => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.0035.0002.0300] [.1182.0020.0008.0044]
êE => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.003C.0002.0302] [.119D.0020.0008.0045]
ēF => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.005B.0002.0304] [.11D5.0020.0008.0046]
```

and:

```
è 1 => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.0035.0002.0300] [*0209.0020.0002.0020] [.1138.0020.0002.0031]
ê 5 => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.003C.0002.0302] [*0209.0020.0002.0020] [.113C.0020.0002.0035]
e 2 => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [*0209.0020.0002.0020] [.1139.0020.0002.0032]
é 4 => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.0032.0002.0301] [*0209.0020.0002.0020] [.113B.0020.0002.0034]
ē 3 => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.005B.0002.0304] [*0209.0020.0002.0020] [.113A.0020.0002.0033]
ë 6 => [.119D.0020.0002.0065] [.0000.0047.0002.0308] [*0209.0020.0002.0020] [.113D.0020.0002.0036]
```

which then compute to the following sorting keys:

```
e => 119D 0000 0020 0000 0002 0000 0065
é => 119D 0000 0020 0032 0000 0002 0002 0000 0065 0301
ë => 119D 0000 0020 0047 0000 0002 0002 0000 0065 0308
è => 119D 0000 0020 0035 0000 0002 0002 0000 0065 0300
ê => 119D 0000 0020 003C 0000 0002 0002 0000 0065 0302
ē => 119D 0000 0020 005B 0000 0002 0002 0000 0065 0304
```

and:

```
eA => 119D 1141 0000 0020 0020 0000 0002 0008 0000 0065 0041
éB => 119D 1157 0000 0020 0032 0020 0000 0002 0002 0008 0000 0065 0301 0042
ëC => 119D 116F 0000 0020 0047 0020 0000 0002 0002 0008 0000 0065 0308 0043
èD => 119D 1182 0000 0020 0035 0020 0000 0002 0002 0008 0000 0065 0300 0044
êE => 119D 119D 0000 0020 003C 0020 0000 0002 0002 0008 0000 0065 0302 0045
ēF => 119D 11D5 0000 0020 005B 0020 0000 0002 0002 0008 0000 0065 0304 0046
```

and:

```
è 1 => 119D 0209 1138 0000 0020 0035 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0002 0000 0065 0300 0020 0031
ê 5 => 119D 0209 113C 0000 0020 003C 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0002 0000 0065 0302 0020 0035
e 2 => 119D 0209 1139 0000 0020 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0000 0065 0020 0032
é 4 => 119D 0209 113B 0000 0020 0032 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0002 0000 0065 0301 0020 0034
ē 3 => 119D 0209 113A 0000 0020 005B 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0002 0000 0065 0304 0020 0033
ë 6 => 119D 0209 113D 0000 0020 0047 0020 0020 0000 0002 0002 0002 0002 0000 0065 0308 0020 0036
```

which again gives these three sorted results:

```
e
é
è
ê
ë
ē
```

and

```
eA
éB
ëC
èD
êE
ēF
```

and

```
è 1
e 2
ē 3
é 4
ê 5
ë 6
```

Comment: Hi Patrick. Thanks for posting this detailed info. A few notes: **1)** You can ignore Code Page 1252. That is for `VARCHAR` (i.e. non-Unicode) data, which is not being used here. That is why the `ē` character works just fine. **2)** The "collation-charts" info is a bit outdated. It is for a previous version of this Collation and they haven't posted anything since 2009. **3)** The Unicode version here is definitely not the latest (Version 10). The `_100_` series Collations came with SQL 2008, so this would be Unicode 5.0 or 5.1: http://www.unicode.org/standard/versions/#TUS_Earlier_Versions

Comment: I do not think the `allKeys.txt`  changes between Unicode version, besides the addition of new characters, so the above should remain true but of course it could be redone with the previous old data, I just lack the energy of putting again some hours into it. As for CP1252 it was  just coming from the definition given by MS-SQL (I do not use this product myself).

Comment: **1)** There probably aren't major changes between versions, but I am pretty sure that there are weight / classification corrections, at the very least. But yes, I certainly get the time constraints ;) **2)** Regarding CP1252, I was mentioning it because the concept of Code Pages does not exist within Unicode. Unicode is a means of never needing code pages. The MS doc is admittedly unclear on this, but it does mention towards the top "_The code page used to store non-Unicode character data._". You are correct that the one character isn't in CP1252, but Code Pages do not come into play here.

Comment: Yes, I never said anything about code page related to Unicode. It is just MS SQL documentation that says that this collation name does the work with "code page 1252". It probably makes no sense (It does not to me, but again, not an user of it) but it is what is written in the documentation of this software. As for redoing the job, feel free to do so or just provide the changes about sorting related to the characters in play here betwen Unicode 5 and latest, if there are and if you want. I believe my answer stand as it is, is precise and builds the results based on the input, not the other way.

Comment: **3)** re: sentence #1: while mostly about Unicode, this question is an OS issue since MS implemented the spec and might not have done it all and/or might have made some mistakes. I did find 2 bugs in .NET regarding how it determines the "category" or "block" that a particular character is in (they were misidentifying a small segment of characters). Also, this _is_ , at least slightly, a SQL Server issue, only because SQL Server has effectively a snapshot of each Collation at a point in time (for consistency between versions), so they could have what is now SQL Server-specific behavior.

Comment: re: CP1252 / Code Pages: I think you misunderstand the MS documentation because it is poorly worded. It only uses Code Page 1252 when applied to `VARCHAR` / non-Unicode data. The same Collation can be used with both `NVARCHAR` (Unicode) and `VARCHAR` (non-Unicode) data. When used with `NVARCHAR`, Code Page is ignored. When applied to `VARCHAR` is CP1252. Also, I am not suggesting that you (or I) re-do anything. I was just pointing out that using the latest version _might_ yield confusing results. I will see if I can find any differences to at least get a sense of the scope of them.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I redid all computations with Unicode 5.1, so I hope that will help (while the collation arrays do change, the final sort keys are similar and the sorting results again the same). But I think I will stop arguing with you on the other points.

Answer (score 17):

The behavior you are seeing here is due, in a general sense, to the fact that the [Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/tr10-36.html#Multi_Level_Comparison) allows for complex, multi-level sorting. More specifically:

1. Sorting is not Comparison:

   Determining whether two strings are the same or different is fairly straight forward (given a particular locale/language and set of sensitivities). But determining the order of 2 or more strings can be highly complex.
2. Sorting is done in a series of steps, with each step applied to the entire string, not character by character:

   1. Standard: sort base characters (regardless of accent and case differences)
   2. IF Accent-sensitive, apply accent / diacritic weights
   3. IF Case-sensitive, apply casing weights

When you sort by `col1` (single character), it first determines that all characters have the same weight since they are all "**e**". Next, it applies the accent / diacritic weights. There are no casing differences so the third step wouldn't change anything. So the only differences are in step 2, which is why there is a preferred order for those rows based on `col1`.

When you sort by `col2` (two characters), it first determines that each row has a different weight since both characters are used to determine the sort weight (e.g. "**ea**", "**eb**", etc). Next, it applies the accent / diacritic weights. There are no casing differences so the third step wouldn't change anything. So there are differences in steps 1 and 2 this time. But since the differences in step 1 have already been applied to each string before the weights of step 2 are considered, the weights from step 2 don't have any effect on the ordering; they would only apply if weights from step 1 for two or more rows were the same.

The following adaptation of the sample code from the question hopefully illustrates the sorting behavior described above. I added some additional rows and an additional column to help show the impact of the Collation being case-sensitive (since the original sample data is all lower-case):

**SETUP**

```
USE [tempdb];

-- DROP TABLE dbo.OddSort;
CREATE TABLE dbo.OddSort
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 NVARCHAR(5) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS,
    col2 NVARCHAR(5) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS,
    col3 NVARCHAR(5) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
);
GO

INSERT dbo.OddSort (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (N'e', N'eA', N'e A')
     , (N'ê', N'êE', N'ê E')
     , (N'é', N'éH', N'é H')
     , (N'ë', N'ëC', N'ë C')
     , (N'E', N'EG', N'E G')
     , (N'Ë', N'ëh', N'ë h')
     , (N'è', N'èD', N'è D')
     , (N'é', N'éB', N'é B')
     , (N'ë', N'ëH', N'ë H')
     , (N'ē', N'ēF', N'ē F');
```

**TEST 1**

```
SELECT [id], [col1], UNICODE([col1]) AS [CodePoint]
FROM dbo.OddSort 
ORDER BY col1;
```

Returns:

```
id    col1    CodePoint
1     e       101
5     E       69
8     é       233
3     é       233
7     è       232
2     ê       234
4     ë       235
9     ë       235
6     Ë       203
10    ē       275
```

What we can see in the results above:

1. The Code Point is not determining the sort order
2. The non-accented characters are sorted before the accented characters (within the same letter: **f** would still come after all of these). Clearly, accent weights are applied before case weights.
3. Lower-case sorts before upper-case within the same accented (or non-accented) character (i.e. the **e** then **E**, and the **ë** then **Ë**). This tailoring is used by most of the Windows Collations, while most of the SQL Server Collations sort upper-case first.

**TEST 2**

```sql
SELECT [id], [col2]
FROM dbo.OddSort 
ORDER BY col2;
```

Returns:

```
id    col2
1     eA
8     éB
4     ëC
7     èD
2     êE
10    ēF
5     EG
3     éH
6     ëh
9     ëH
```

What we can see in the results above:

1. First-level sorting truly is the base characters. If it were accents / diacritics then the **ëC** (id = 4), **ēF** (id = 10), and **EG** (id = 5) rows would not be where they are. If it were casing, then the **EG** (id = 5) row would not be where it is.
2. Second-level sorting truly is the accents / diacritics. This explains why the last three rows are **éH** -> **ëh** -> **ëH** instead of **ëh** -> **éH** -> **ëH** (i.e. IDs 3 -> 6 -> 9 instead of 6 -> 3 -> 9).
3. Third-level sorting truly is the casing. This is why the last 2 rows are **ëh** -> **ëH**, since lower-case sorts first.

**TEST 3**

```sql
SELECT [id], [col3]
FROM dbo.OddSort 
ORDER BY col3;
```

Returns:

```
id    col3
1     e A
8     é B
4     ë C
7     è D
2     ê E
10    ē F
5     E G
3     é H
6     ë h
9     ë H
```

What we can see in the results above:

1. The sort order is exactly the same as in Test 2. The only difference in the test values here is that there is a space between each character, removing the possibility of contextual rules. Hence, we know that the reason for the difference in sort order for `col2` in the question is again due to "Multi-Level Comparison", and *not* "Contextual Sensitivity".

---

**Additional notes:**

1. With regarding to getting the exact rules, that is not as easy as it should be. The problem with getting concrete explanations of these rules is that the Unicode sorting rules, while definitely documented, are a recommendation. It is up to vendors, such as Microsoft, to implement those recommendations. Microsoft did not implement the recommendations exactly as stated in the Unicode documentation so there is a disconnect there (similar to how neither the HTML or CSS specifications are implemented as completely, nor even in the same way, across vendors). Then, there are different versions of the Windows Collations (you are using version `100` which came out with SQL Server 2008) and that is tied to a Unicode version that is much older than the current version of Unicode or of the [ICU Collation demo](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/collation.html) is using. For example, the **What's New in SQL Server 2008 Collations** section of the ["Collation and Unicode Support" documentation for SQL Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143503(v=sql.100).aspx#Anchor_0) makes 2 very interesting points about what is "new" to the `_100_` series Collations:

   1. > Unicode 5.0 case table.

      Unicode 5.0 was published in July of 2006 (well, the character database was released then, and the full spec followed in late 2006). The current version is 10.0 which was published in June of 2017. And given the release pattern of the past 4 years, it is likely that version 11.0 will be out sometime mid-2018.
   2. > Weighting has been added to previously non-weighted characters that would have compared equally.

      Those weights were more than likely defined in the Unicode Standard, just not in this implementation of it.

   Still, the UCA documentation linked above is a good place to start.
2. Sort Keys used by Windows / .NET / SQL Server are not exactly the same as shown in the Unicode Standard (See @Patrick's answer) or implemented in the [ICU](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/collation.html). To see what Windows / .NET / SQL Server use, you can try the [CompareInfo.GetSortKey Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.getsortkey). I created a SQLCLR UDF to pass in these values and get the sort key. Please note that I am using SQL Server 2017 on Windows 10 with .NET Framework 4.5 - 4.6.1 installed, so .NET *should* be using Unicode 6.0.0. Also, Level4 is not being used for these strings.

   ```
   CHAR    L1     L2     L3     L4
   e      0E21
   E      0E21           12
   ë      0E21    13
   Ë      0E21    13     12
   ```

   Looking at these sort keys for Test 1, and realizing that the levels are sorted like multiple columns within an `ORDER BY` clause (L3 is sorted within same values of L2, which is sorted within same values of L1), should illustrate that the reason for the behavior noted in the question is in fact the multi-level sorting capability of Unicode. Likewise:

   ```
   CHAR       L1         L2       L3       L4
   EG      0E210E25              1212
   éH      0E210E2C      0E      0212
   ëh      0E210E2C      13
   ëH      0E210E2C      13      0212
   ```

   Looking at some of the sort keys for Test 2, we can see that base characters are sorted first (L1), then accents are sorted (L2), and then casing is sorted (L3).
3. Since the datatype is `NVARCHAR`, we are only concerned with Unicode Code Points and sorting algorithms, hence the use of the `UNICODE()` function in TEST 1. While Code Pages are specified by most Collations, they only pertain to `VARCHAR` data. Meaning, while Code Page 1252 is specified by the `Latin1_General*` series of Collations, that can be ignored here.
4. The weights described in the Default Unicode Collation Element Table (DUCET) ([Version 5.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/5.0.0/allkeys.txt) which should map to the `_100_` series Collations) are fine for US English, but not other locales / languages. Other languages need to *start* with the DUCET and then apply locale-specific override rules as defined by the Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) project. From what I can tell, versions 1.4 / 1.4.1 were released in 2006. To get those overrides, download the CLDR 1.4 "core" file via http://unicode.org/Public/cldr/1.4.0/core.zip, then, in that zip file, go to the **collation** folder and find the XML file corresponding to the locale being used. Those files contain just the overrides, and are not complete sets of collation rules.